# visualizing Optical flow in matlab

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

I have an image with size 240*320 and I have the optical flow result with vertical and horizontal values. I need to visualize Optical flow by arrows on original image. I know that I have to use quiver function. Something like:

```
imshow(image)
hold on
quiver(vx,vy)
hold off
```

But what I get is a blue square instead of quivers.

Answer (score 2):

An entirely blue square is probably caused by way too many arrows plotted close together.

For example, the following code will produce an easy-to-see (if not very meaningful) set of arrow:

```
figure
data = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(data)
s = size(data);
hold on
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:50:s(2),1:50:s(1));
px = cos(x);
py = sin(y);
quiver(x,y,px,py)
```

[image: Nice quiver plot]

And this will produce an entirely blue plot:

```
figure
data = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(data)
s = size(data);
hold on
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:1:s(2),1:1:s(1)); % arrow spacing is too close! 
px = cos(x);
py = sin(y);
quiver(x,y,px,py)
```

[image: blue plot with too many arrows]