# What are the Coordinate Axes alignment in plot generated by quiver

Tags: matlab

I am using quiver to plot optical flow over my image using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935160/visualizing-optical-flow-in-matlab) answer.

Following is taken from matlab quiver documentation page

> A quiver plot displays velocity vectors as arrows with components
>   (u,v) at the points (x,y).
>
> For example, the first vector is defined by
>   components u(1),v(1) and is displayed at the point x(1),y(1).

We know that while reading an image the index(1,1) is at top left.

Now where does quiver assumes it's origin and in which direction it assumes the alignment of axes while generating the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the x axis values increase to the right and the y axis increase towards the top.

However `imshow` which is used in the linked answer reverses the y axis direction, similar to `axis('image')`. This is because image data is generally stored with the top left of the image appearing first in the data.

The directions can be checked with:

```
get(gca,'ydir')
get(gca,'xdir')
```

if `hold` is on `quiver` will plot using this reversed y direction so the origin is in the top left. (assuming the lowest value for the axis is 0)

---

If `hold` is not on or the directions are not reversed the origin will be at the bottom left and `quiver` will use with the default axis directions. (again assuming values>=0)